# sqlのカラムの命名規則について

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

groupsテーブルとusersテーブルがあったとします。

groupsテーブルのカラムが、
・ id　
・ group_id 
・ name

idがuuid、group_idがユーザーが見ることができるidになっています。

usersテーブルのカラムが
・ id
・ user_id
・ group_id 
・ name

idがuuid、user_idがユーザーが見ることができるid、group_idがgroupsのidに紐づいています。

この場合、usersのgroup_idがgroup_idではなくidに紐づいているので、
とてもややこしいと感じます。

こういった場合はどのように名前をつけるべきでしょうか。

Comment: リレーションを具体的に記載した方がよいと思います。(`groups.id`は`users.group_id`の外部キーである、等)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ツールの制約もあるでしょうが、主キーは何を表すものかが分かるように修飾することをすすめます。

「ユーザーが見ることができる ID」は、name と同じくリレーションシップに意味のない文字列と受取りました。この名前を工夫すれば理解しやすくなるでしょう。

たとえば、下記のように変更してはどうでしょうか。

```
groups
- group_id (←id)
- id_friendly (←group_id)
- name

users
- user_id (←id)
- group_id
- id_friendly (←user_id)
- name
```

Answer (score 2):

「異なる意味なのに同じ名前」がややこしさの原因なので、「異なる意味なら異なる名前」になるようにするようにすればよいわけですが、これをどうするかはアプリケーション全体を見ないと決められない話です。

---

groupsのgroup_idの名前を変えるのが自明で短絡的な方法ですが、group_idが真にIDなのであればリレーションをそっちに張るとか、それならidいらないのではとか、IDじゃないのであればgroup_idとは一体何者でそれにふさわしい名前は何かとか、別の視点でgroup_idが既存の名前付けルールにより決まる名前なのであればそのルール自体見直さないといけないのでは、とか、質問の内容だけでは考えようがないですし、考えられるための材料を質問に記載するのは難しいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

まず、ややこしいと感じるかどうかは主観によるかな、と思います。

`users.group_id` が外部キーで、 `groups` のPKであるところの `id` 参照している、というのは私から見ると特に違和感はありません。
むしろ次のような場合だと違和感があります:

- `id`がPKでない
- `groups.group_id`や`users.user_id`がPKである
- `users.group_id`が、PKではない`groups.group_id`を参照している

---

主キーの意味で`id`という名前を使い、また他方でユニークな識別子(identifier)の意味でも`id`という名前を使っているのが違和感の根源かと思います。対応案としては:

- `group_id` -> `group_name` などにリネームする

  - `id`といえば普通PKのことだろ派。ORMフレームワークのデフォルトではそうなっているものも多いかと思います。
- `id` -> `pk` などにリネームする

  - PKなんだから`pk`で良いだろ派。現状通り`group_id`, `user_id`がユニークであることが名前から想起できます。

私の宗派は前者です。

Comment: 例えば Oracle からデータベースを始めると HR サンプルスキーマが `エンティティ名 + ID` なんですね。それが普通と思いこむわけです。感覚でそれが主キーと認められない文化の方がいるとは。本筋とは外れますが収穫でした。

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E96517_01/comsc/HR-sample-schema-table-descriptions.html#GUID-506C25CE-FA5D-472A-9C4C-F9EF200823EE